# Android JSON string server not show arabic character

Tags: android, asp.net, json

I write simple app in android,but when I send arabic character with JSON to asp.net server page,in server not known arabic character and show me this:

```
["????"]
```

Comment: Try to send the arabic characters parameter using url_encode()

Comment: @SarimJavaidKhan  hi my friend,thanks to read my post,but what is url_encode function ?

Comment: URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted over the Internet.
It is a simple function that converts string to a particular format that can be transmitted.
send data from android using "urlencode" method and receive data on server using "urldecode" method.

Comment: @SarimJavaidKhan thanks,can you give me a any tutorial or example?in android or asp.net?

Comment: See this url. It is not exactly according to your scenario but it would give you the sense.

http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-encode-java-string-send-web-server-safe-url

Comment: If this helps you dont forget to upvote

Comment: @SarimJavaidKhan sure my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Encode arabic string and then send that string,

```
public static String getEncodedString(String str) {
    String ret = null;
    try {
        ret = Base64.encode(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: But when i getByte method,android error:can not resolve encode(byte)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static String getEncodedString(String str) {
    String myString= null;
    try {
        myString= new String(str.getBytes(), "ISO-8859-1");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return myString;
}
```

Comment: thanks my friend,but it shows unknown character again.

Comment: can you post the json

Answer (score 0):

my code :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   countrynamemail=value.toString();
}
   private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            TextView mytext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            TourMyCountry country=new TourMyCountry();

            String base64=null;
            try{
                byte[] data = countrynamemail.getBytes("UTF-8");
                 base64= Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);


            }catch (Exception e){

            }

            country.name= base64;
            return POST(urls[0],country);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   countrynamemail=value.toString();
}
   private class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            TextView mytext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            TourMyCountry country=new TourMyCountry();

            String base64=null;
            try{
                byte[] data = countrynamemail.getBytes("UTF-8");
                 base64= Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);


            }catch (Exception e){

            }

            country.name= base64;
            return POST(urls[0],country);
        }

 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Log.d("My Return BackUp is:",result.toString());
        ArrayList<String> itemsList=new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject JsonObj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String CityName=JsonObj.getString("toas");
                itemsList.add(CityName);

            }
            ListView mylist=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            ArrayAdapter<String> myAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(tourdetail.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemsList);
            mylist.setAdapter(myAdaptor);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After having a lot research of the same problem getting by me. I found the solution.please check and use Charset for change it to UTF-8 set.

```
        sendEnquiryJson.put("comments", comments.getText().toString().trim());
        Charset chars = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        StringBody eMail = new StringBody(sendEnquiryJson.toString(), chars);
```